# Not able to get text between :: before and :: after

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Tried this in XPATH finder in chrome, element is highlighted.. but selenium script gives

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: 
Unable to locate element:

//span[@class='badge badge-pill message message-bot']//p[@class='card-text']
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a space after the class `message-bot` .

So maybe this will work:

`//span[@class='badge badge-pill message message-bot ']//p[@class='card-text']`

Answer (score 0):

To get a text add `.text` after selector
Also, try to use css selector:

```
.badge.badge-pill.message-bot>card-text
```

So, you text be be like:

```
result = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".badge.badge-pill.message-bot>card-text").text
```

Or,

```
result = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='badge badge-pill message message-bot ']/p[@class='card-text']")
```

Most probably you need only one / before `p`. Try both options.